# Dataframe shape when using directlabels + ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following dataframe

```
# Data
Year <- c(1500,1750,2000)
Country1 <- c(10,20,30)
Country2 <- c(30,50,40)
df <- data.frame(Year, Country1, Country2)
```

which I plot with

```
# Plot
require(ggplot2)
myplot <- ggplot(df, aes(Year)) + geom_line(aes(y=Country1)) + geom_line(aes(y=Country2)) + labs(y = "Cows")
```

All good. Then I want to add lines' labels. And I try

```
# Add labels
require(directlabels)
direct.label(myplot)
```

which throws

```
Error in direct.label.ggplot(myplot) : 
  Need colour aesthetic to infer default direct labels.
```

I guess the problem is that my dataframe is not well shaped for `ggplot` because my labels are column names.

Should I reshape my dataframe? How?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to reshape (in my opinion) would be with the `reshape2` package

```
df<-data.frame(
    Year = c(1500, 1750, 2000), 
    Country1 = c(10, 20, 30), 
    Country2 = c(30, 50, 40)
)

#reshape
library(reshape2)
mm<-melt(df, id.var="Year")

#plot
myplot2 <- ggplot(mm, aes(Year, value, color=variable))+ geom_line()  + labs(y = "Cows")

#add labels
library(directlabels)
direct.label(myplot2)
```

[image]

This way we can provide the proper "color" aesthetic that the `direct.labels` function is looking for.